# How to transform ASP.NET URL without URL routing or URL rewrite?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing, friendly-url

I am using ASP.NET 2.0 on IIS6 therefore I can’t use system.web.routing. I’ve tried a few URL rewriters but none did what I wanted.

I basically need to transform (read/parse then redirect) URL ***1*** into ***2*** with minimum IIS configuration because I don't have the full authority to reconfigure web servers (i.e. ISAP on IIS6 or install 3rd party extensions/libraries). And I can’t transform URL into ***3*** because all the physical links will break.

1. http://www.url.com/abc123
2. http://www.url.com/default.aspx?code=abc123
3. http://www.url.com/abc123/default.aspx?code=abc123

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 404 error handler, e.g. 404.aspx. In that page, parse request URL and extract code using `Request.Path`. Then, redirect to default.aspx?code=abc123.

You should be able to set 404 (page not found) handler to 404.aspx for your website, most hosting providers allow that.

Comment: I was going to manually do the parsing and redirect in Application_Error (global.asax) because I couldn't get rid of the aspxerrorpath querry string as I can't capture the value of /abc123 before aspxerrorpath is thrown because Request.Path is alwasy the URL of the 404 error page.

Comment: Make sure you set 404 handler in IIS, not in web.config.

Comment: Do you recommend Application_Error (global.asax) than 404? Becuase I don't have too much control over web servers and we have more than 1 web servers so I prefer the "soft" way. For any IIS setting change, it takes weeks to get approved...

Comment: If you get Application_Error event for extension-less URLs like `http://www.url.com/abc123` by all means, use it. Otherwise you need to configure IIS to use your 404 handler.

Comment: I've configured my dev IIS to forward 404 to my 404 page yet Request.Url and Request.Path both showing the path to 404 page and Request.UrlReferrer is null.

Comment: I sort of don't want to use ApplicationError unless I have no other choice becuase by doing "URL transofmration" in AppError has performance impacts I believe.

Comment: Ok I figured out that I need to use Request["aspxerrorpath"] to read the path. Thanks!!!

Comment: It's so obvious to get value from QueryString I don't know what I was thinking... ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you look at using a custom transform with UrlRewriter.net. [This link](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/11/advanced-url-rewriting-for-rest-of-us.html) details how you can do it with the `Intelligencia.UrlRewriter` assembly (about 3/4 of the way down the page). Hopefully is good enough to do what you need.

Comment: I don't think URL rewrite will work because I don't want the URL to be rewritten I only need the URL to be read/parsed then redirect.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlLink canonicalTag = new HtmlLink();
    canonicalTag.Href = "http://www.url.com/default.aspx";
    canonicalTag.Attributes["rel"] = "canonical";
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(canonicalTag);
}
```

http://codersbarn.com/post/2009/02/21/ASPNET-SEO-and-the-Canonical-Tag.aspx